# Finding and visualizing the Linear Regression Curve for N days at a time

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, curve-fitting

Want to find the linear regression line every n days, this is typically known as a 'linear regression curve'.

I have time series data in which I need to find the linear regression curve every n days - essentially the slope every n days will change and there will be a new linear regression line every n days - all of them being connected on a graph later on.

```
def slope_intercept(x_val, y_val):
x = np.array(x_val)
y = np.array(y_val)
m = ( ( (np.mean(x)*np.mean(y) ) - np.mean(x*y)) /
    ( ( np.mean(x)*np.mean(x)) - np.mean(x*x)))

m = round(m,2)
b=(np.mean(y)-np.mean(x)*m)
b=round(b,2)
return m,b

m,b=slope_intercept(future.index.tolist(), future['close'].tolist())
future['reg_line'] = [(m*x)+b for x in future.index.tolist()]
```

Once this is found, I would like to visualize it on a graph. A picture of said visualization is below, as well as example of the code for linear regression of the entire time of data. I am guessing it is some type of for-loop to do this?
[image: Picture of the linear-regression-curve I am trying to make, disregard the candlesticks]

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

linregress(x,y)
```

x and y are arrays or lists.

Comment: Gets me a straight line for the entire timeframe in the dataset. I need multiple lines for every n-days. That make sense?

Comment: from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit([[getattr(t, 'x%d' % i) for i in range(1, 8)] for t in texts],
        [t.y for t in texts])

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? What is the getattr() portion doing? Thanks